# PHP to make an SQL query to indicate which rows contain text in specific column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, mysqli

I have a table that is reading from an SQL database full of job numbers and the relevant customers and machine order. I also have a "notes" column in the "operations" table which will sometimes contain text that is entered by others. What I need is to display some sort of indication that text has been entered into the notes column for the specific jobID and operation.

So far, I've tried the empty function but I don't think I'm displaying the results of the query properly so its constantly saying that there's text for all jobs.

Here is the relevant code below:

```
$conN = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER);
        if (!$conN) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conN));} // Check Connection

        mysqli_select_db($conN,"jms");
        $jid = $row['jobID'];
        $opn = $row['operation'];
        $highlight = mysqli_query($conN,"SELECT notes FROM operations WHERE jobID=$jid AND operation=$opn");



        if (empty($highlight)) {
            echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>"."</td>";
        }else{
            echo "<td style='background-color:red;'>"."</td>";
        }
```

What I'm getting is red in all cells, while I want only the cells that contain text in the "notes" column to display as red, while the empty ones should appear blue.

Anybody able to help?

Comment: use `$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($highlight )` and check for `$rowcount` `if (empty($rowcount))`then it will highlight blue else red...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display cells that contain text in the "notes" column to display as red, while the empty ones should appear blue first to need to fetch data from your result set then apply your condition

```
 $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($highlight);
if ($rowcount > 0) {
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($highlight))
        if (isset($data['notes']) && $data['notes'] != "") {
            echo "<td style='background-color:red;'>" . "</td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>" . "</td>";
        }
} else {
    echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>" . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: I think he only want to output the box once. You will output it for every entry containing a note. Easier to change the sql and check the number of rows as that stops you needed to fetch the values

Comment: @Brett before downvote check the OP comments before!!

Comment: Update your answer so it's better for him and i will upvote

Comment: @Brett Ans if OP check the condition in sql then blue rows never comes!! Op want to shoe empty roes in blue

Comment: Yes if he adds the correct code in place, see the other 2 answers to this question for better solutions

Comment: @Brett tell me one thing without fetching data how we compare the value of `notes` is empty or not!! `mysqli_num_rows` just check the query return result or not.

Comment: I can't remove my downvote until you update the answer

Comment: @Saty please look at Manjeet's answer, it adds a change to the sql query to check the value of notes. Then you don't need to do any checks in the php or fetch any rows. num_rows is already in the response from the query.

Comment: @Brett I check Manjeet's answer But after using that code OP code never comes into false condition i.e blue rows never rows show!! But in question OP want to show empty rows in blue color. Don't forget to read question carefully!!

Comment: @Saty. I think you are missing it. empty($rowcount) will be true when there are no rows returned. Because it's only returning rows that have a note. There is no more discussion. Manjeets answer is the exact same as yours, except he is doing the logic in the sql and you are doing it in php which seems less efficient as it accesses the harddrive more

Comment: @Brett, what Saty suggested has worked perfectly for me. I don't know why you're still arguing about it.

Comment: @Eksepshon i was just trying to show him that his code was less efficient than the other guys answer.

Comment: @Brett, I tried Manjeet's and it didn't work for me. I'm sure there are multiple methods to the solution, and Saty provided one of them. It's not a competition.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with this and check...

```
<?php 
$conN = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER);
if (!$conN) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conN));} // Check Connection

mysqli_select_db($conN,"jms");
$jid = $row['jobID'];
$opn = $row['operation'];
$highlight = mysqli_query($conN,"SELECT notes FROM operations WHERE jobID=$jid AND operation=$opn AND notes !=''");
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($highlight);


if(empty($rowcount)) 
{
    echo "<td style='background-color:blue;'>"."</td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td style='background-color:red;'>"."</td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You aren't checking whether notes has a value anywhere. You're just checking the rows that would be returned. The poster needs to change their sql to ensure that they check for the presence of notes. See my answer below

Comment: Perfect (also, depending on table structure it's good to be AND notes IS NOT NULL) in the sql too. As text columns can sometimes default to NULL when no value is present.